# facing issues with flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I just added flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0 to my `pubspec.yaml` and after i wrote the code for notification in `main.dart` and it just starting showing this error .

here is my console :

```
    Launching lib\main.dart on RMX1851 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/flutter_local_notifications_plugin.dart:12:1: Error: 'SelectNotificationCallback' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/typedefs.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/typedefs.dart'.
import 'typedefs.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:25:1: Error: 'SelectNotificationCallback' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/typedefs.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/typedefs.dart'.
import 'typedefs.dart';
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:37:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:105:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:131:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:165:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:190:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:213:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:236:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:261:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:430:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:465:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:501:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:526:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:548:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:570:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:654:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:683:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-6.0.0/lib/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:705:5: Error: 'validateId' is imported from both 'package:flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface/src/helpers.dart' and 'package:flutter_local_notifications/src/helpers.dart'.
    validateId(id);
    ^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

and here is my `main.dart` file:

```
import 'package:chatter_box/helperServices/auth.dart';
import 'package:chatter_box/helperServices/profileUpdate.dart';
import 'package:chatter_box/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:chatter_box/screens/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:chatter_box/screens/registration_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    "high_importance_channel",  // id
    "High Importance Notifications", // title
    "This channel is used for important notifications" , // description
importance: Importance.high,
  playSound: true
);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message)async{
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
 print("a bg meesage just came ${message.messageId}");
}

  main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage((message) => _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(message));

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
   await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
     alert: true,
     badge: true,
     sound: true,
   );
  runApp(Chatterbox());
}

class Chatterbox extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.latoTextTheme(
          Theme.of(context).textTheme,
        ),
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FutureBuilder(
        future:AuthMethods().getCurrentUser() ,
        builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot)  {
          if(snapshot.hasData){
          return HomeScreen();}
          else{return WelcomeScreen() ;}
          }

      ),

      routes: {
        WelcomeScreen.id:(context) => WelcomeScreen(),
        RegistrationScreen.id: (context) => RegistrationScreen(),
        // LoginScreen.id :(context) => LoginScreen(),
        HomeScreen.id :(context) => HomeScreen(),
        SignUpPage.id : (context) => SignUpPage(),

      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add `default_notification_channel_id` (i.e. `high_importance_channel` here) in `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`?

Also, if you need to display the notification, refer to the code below (this is how I did it):

```
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

class LocalNotificationService {
  static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static void initialize() {
    final initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_notification'),
    );

    _notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  static Future<void> displayNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    try {
      final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;

      final notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'high_importance_channel',
          'High Importance Notifications',
          'This channel is used for important notifications',
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
        ),
      );

      await _notificationsPlugin.show(
        id,
        message.notification!.title,
        message.notification!.body,
        notificationDetails,
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yes i have added to the `manifest.xml` here is the code `<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="high_importance_channel" />`

Comment: but after i add the flutter_local_notification library it crashes and show this error . but after i remove it , it works fine again

Comment: Looks like this was a plugin side issue and is fixed on `v6.1.0`. Refer to the links below :-

https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/releases/tag/flutter_local_notifications-v6.1.0

https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/1243#issuecomment-886596034

Comment: yes it works fine now , thanks for the help